# './mysql/user.MYD' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)

Tags: mysql

I have installed mysql on Mac Os 10.13 using ' brew install mysql' and when trying to set a password as suggested by brew by command mysql_secure_installation, it throws up an error. Can anyone please guide me

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry the error it throws up is " ... Failed! Error: File './mysql/user.MYD' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)"

Answer (score -1):

This happens when you install mysql more than once so
Open Terminal and then

> cd /usr/local
>
> open .

Make sure that the latest mysql installed folder is called "mysql" by deleting any other folders  called  "mysql" and rename the last one as "mysql"