# Error mysql user.MYD not found when I try to change password

Tags: mysql

I'm using mac Os Mojave

I want to install Mysql with brew

```
brew install mysql
```

then I tryo to reset password

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

and error show up

```
... Failed! Error: File './mysql/user.MYD' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
```

I try to read and do manything like this

['./mysql/user.MYD' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46213844/mysql-user-myd-not-found-errcode-13-permission-denied)

['./mysql/user.MYD' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46917693/mysql-user-myd-not-found-errcode-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

But it still not fix